# 07 Dodge Caravan with 3.3 cylinders 3 and 6 misfire

Tags: dodge, misfire, caravan

I have a 2007 dodge caravan with a 3.3 with a misfire on cylinders 3 and 6 ( no spark coming from coil to plugs on cylinders). I have changed the plugs the wires. The coil twice and the crank sen. I have check the wires under the top intake and none are broke burnt or cut. I an stumpped on what the problem is. I was hopping someone could help me out with what it may be. I heard it could be the computer? Any help would be appreciated. I should also add that the other 4 cylinders have a strong spark.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you use Mopar parts?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no spark on 2 cylinders that share the same coil, 3 and 6, it is time to check for signal from the pcm, coil driver circuit at the coil.

If it is there, inspect the connector pins for connection integrity.  If it isn't there, then check for signal again at the PCM. If it's at the PCM, find the open in that circuit or run a new wire.  If it isn't, the coil driver inside the PCM has gone bad.

While it is possible that you have replaced the coil 2 times with defective parts, it is unlikely the culprit, and testing for the driver signal (pulsating ground) should verify this.